# Only select post Im clicking on (v-for @click vue.js) but its selecting all saved posts because of the v-for, what can I use instead?

Tags: vue.js, click, size, tailwind-css, v-for

Im doing a little blog project to practice vue.js. Im using composition API script setup. When you write a post it saves in localStorage. When you click on the text in the blog it opens up an overlay and a big sized blogtext. its just that its not only showing the one I clicked on but the other earlier blog posts aswell. How can I focus so it only shows the one I click on. Im using tailwind as css.

[image]

[image]

On this link you can test yourself but here I have some dummytext in before I made it so the note.text will be shown; https://unique-sprinkles-d1a6cd.netlify.app/

```
<template>
    <div v-if="showModal" @click="showModal = false" class="absolute w-screen h-screen bg-black opacity-75 z-10 flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-center">
        <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" class="bg-white  hover:border-red-400 p-4 rounded-full text-2xl font-bold"><p>{{ note.text }}</p></div>
    </div>
<div class="w-6/12 text-center m-auto">
    <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold text-indigo-500 m-5">Blog Posts</h1>
    <div  class="border-2 border-slate-100 rounded-3xl hover:border-red-400" v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" > 
        <div class="relative flex flex-col m-0 justify-around cursor-pointer">
            <button class="absolute top-0 right-0 w-5 h-5 cursor-pointer rounded-full hover:bg-red-400 p-2.5" @click="deleteBtn(note)">x</button>
            <img class="w-24 h-24 p-3.5 rounded-full" :src="note.img"> 
            <p class="text-xs text-right pr-3.5"> {{ note.writer }}</p>
            <p class="text-lg font-bold"> {{ note.headline }}</p>
            <p @click="showModal = true" class="text-left p-3.5 text-sm"> {{ note.text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const notes = ref([]);

notes.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));

    function deleteBtn(note){
        notes.value.splice(notes.value.indexOf(note), 1);
        localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes.value));


        notes.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
        console.log(notes.value)
    }

const showModal = ref(false)
</script>
```

after changes it looks like this; How can I make the empty squares dissapear and also the opacity to 0 in the white textarea so no text from the behind shows. Ive tried tailwind opacity functions but doesnt work.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method you can use for conditional rendering.

When dealing with `v-loops` without using a child component, you can use `index` in the loop then conditionally render it with `v-if="selectedIndex = index`.

In the modal section, you add the `v-if` like this

```html
<div 
  v-if="showModal" 
  @click="showModal = false" 
  class="absolute w-screen h-screen bg-black opacity-75 z-10 flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-center"
>
    <div 
      v-for="(note, index) in notes" 
      :key="note.id" 
      class="bg-white hover:border-red-400 p-4 rounded-full text-2xl font-bold"
    >
      <p v-if="selectedIndex === index">{{ note.text }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in the place where you rendered the text to be clicked, you add a click event to update `selectedIndex` when you click on different rendered contents with their relevant index.

```html
<div
  v-for="(note, index) in notes"
  :key="note.id"
  class="border-2 border-slate-100 rounded-3xl hover:border-red-400"
  @click="selectedIndex = index"
> 
   <div 
      class="relative flex flex-col m-0 justify-around cursor-pointer"
   >
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

then in the script tag, just add a ref of the `selectedIndex`

```js
const selectedIndex = ref(null)
```

**Note**:
If your `@click="showModal = true"` is faster than the selectedIndex update, you will get a "delayed" update. To fix this you want to convert the `@click="showModal = true"` into a function, which includes the `updateIndex` and this `showModal` reassigning.

It would look something like this

```html
<template>
// other parts...
<p @click="updateValues(index)" class="text-left p-3.5 text-sm"> {{ note.text }}</p>
// other parts...
</template>

<script setup>
// ... your other functions above

const updateValues = (index) => {
  selectedIndex.value = index
  showModal.value = true
}
</script>
```

Anyhow, I think it would be better to split those 2 items (the modal and the render text) into different components, that way you will be able to have an easier time handling the logic.

Comment: thank you very much now its only the clicked text that shows. I added the result in the question last picture. I stil see some small empty squares. And do youo know how I can make the opacity zero? i tried with tailwind opacity-0 but then nothing shows. Thanks in advance

Comment: @tocajossan move around your `v-if` and your `class`. I recommend putting `v-if` on the top level which covers all of your `divs` that has styling, which means you create additional div covering your `p` with the classes. Note that it is not recommended to put `v-if` on the same element as your `v-for`

Comment: <div v-if="showModal" @click="showModal = false" 
        class="absolute w-screen h-screen bg-black opacity-75 z-10 flex cursor-pointer 
        items-center justify-center">
        <div v-for="(note, index) in notes" 
        :key="note.id" 
        class="bg-white p-8 rounded-xl text-2xl font-bold">
        <p v-if="selectedIndex === index">{{ note.text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div> I think I have as you described, or did I miss something? Should I put an extra div that covers all divs, also the underneath ones?

Comment: @tocajossan the latter, because right now what is being filtered out is just the text if you noticed. We are just filtering the `p` tag, so to also filter out the modal, we need to move the `v-if` to also cover the modal. Basically the easiest solution in this case, is to move all of your classes 2 elements down.

Comment: Thank you now it only shows the text im clicking on :)) But the opacity in the white space shows the text underneath and the picture. I have set opacity-100 but it doesnt change. How can I fix the opacity in the white space and stil have opacity-75 ont he black space? thanks in advance